# Can't get rid of the Restart option in my Eclipse RCP app

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have this app built using Eclipse RCP. The File menu in the ToolBar is defined as follows in the class that extends ActionBarAdvisor:

```
    @Override
    protected void makeActions(final IWorkbenchWindow window)
    {
        // Other actions...

        this.exitAction = ActionFactory.QUIT.create(window);
        register(this.exitAction);
        this.exitAction.setText("E&xit ...");

        // Other actions...
    }

    @Override
    protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar)
    {
        MenuManager fileMenu = new MenuManager("&File", IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_FILE);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        fileMenu.add(new Separator());
        // Add other actions to the menu...
        fileMenu.add(new Separator());
        fileMenu.add(this.exitAction);
    }
```

In the resulting File menu, I am expecting a bunch of options, then a last separator and the Exit option, alone. Instead, there is an extra File->Restart option above the exit one. If I remove the exit action from the code, the restart option disapears with the exit one. When I put it back, they both come back.

Even weirder: this does not happen in SLES 12 (there is only the Exit option), only in SLES 15. I also have another app with very similar code not showing this behavior.

According to [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=197922) old thread, this restart option is an old thing, nothing explains why it appears on its own on SLES 15.

Among the things I tried, there was adding this in the plugin.xml file:

```
<!-- disable menu items... -->
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
        <activity
              id="my.project.hidemenuitemsactivity"
              name="Hide Menu Items Activity">
        </activity>
        
        <!-- Successfuly hide other menu items -->

        <!-- "File->Restart..." -->
        <activityPatternBinding
              activityId="my.project.hidemenuitemsactivity"
              isEqualityPattern="true"
              pattern="org.eclipse.ui.file.restartWorkbench">
        </activityPatternBinding>
        
    </extension>
```

I also tried to list the items in the menu bar manager object (`menuBarManager.getItems();`) to find the extra one and get rid of it with `item.setVisible(false);`, but as far as I can tell there is not extra item that would correspond to the restart button.

These were my best guesses, but I tried other things. This menu option will not go away.

Comment: It is contributed to the menu using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point by the `org.eclipse.ui.ide.application` plug-in.